# Antlr4 C# runtime exception

Tags: antlr4

This is a stripped down version of my grammar file:

```
grammar csv;
csv_list                 : ( TEXT | LETTERS | NUMBER ) (COMMA csv_list)* ;               
any_literal              : TEXT | LETTERS | NUMBER ;

fragment DIGIT           : [0-9] ;
DOT                      : '.' ;
COMMA                    : ',' ;
LETTERS                  : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUMBER                   : DIGIT+ ;
TEXT                     : [0-9a-zA-Z]+ ;

WHITESPACE               : ' ' -> skip;
```

I get a runtime error while trying to instantiate the context (in my case the context class name is `Csv_listContext`).

Note that the `NUMBER` and `LETTERS` lexer rules are relevant for the rest of the grammar, so I cannot remove them.

I get an "argument cannot be null" exception when running the parser in C# runtime.

Any suggestion to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

**P.S**
I know this is not a complete CSV grammar, and that there are CSV grammars out there that do work, this is only a stripped down version of the grammar I am working on.

**UPDATE** the tested input was 1,1232,sdfsdf,123,fff,2e,f2

Comment: Open `obj\Debug\csvParser.cs`, read it and set break points at proper places. Then you can debug and understand the internals.

Comment: thanks @LexLi. I saw that in the Csv_listContext class, the call to `_alt = Interpreter.AdaptivePredict(TokenStream,0,Context);` resulted in an `ArgumentNullException`

this led me to think that the recursion in the parser rule is causing it. Changed the grammer to: `csv_list            : any_literal (COMMA any_literal)* ; ` and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who gets this error, here is how I (kinda) fixed it:

```
grammar csv;

csv_list            : any_literal (COMMA any_literal)* 
                    ;

any_literal         : TEXT | LETTERS | NUMBER
                    ;

fragment DIGIT           : [0-9] ;
DOT                      : '.' ;
COMMA                    : ',' ;
LETTERS                  : [a-zA-Z]+ ;
NUMBER                   : DIGIT+ ;
TEXT                     : [0-9a-zA-Z]+ ;
WHITESPACE               : ' ' -> skip;
```

This probably worked since there is no recursion in the `csv_list` parser rule.